# Do multiple classes on html tag always affect rendering performance?

Tags: html, css, performance, dom, render

Came across an [interesting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4KAWf_fKbM) about debugging rendering performance in Chrome devtools. In his lesson Umar identifies the changing of a CSS class on the `html` tag as the source of a rendering bottleneck. Devtools shows that changing this class potentially affects the 3,874 elements in the DOM below `html` and triggers an expensive `recalculate style` operation.

In the past I've added CSS classes to my `html` or `body` tag as a convenient way to express the state of the page at that level.

Your CMS may do it for the same purpose. For example, in a WordPress site you may see a bunch of classes like `post-template-default single single-post postid-99999 single-format-standard logged-in category-news subcategory-uk has-hover` on a post's `body` tag.

Should we avoid this practice? Or will it only affect rendering performance when the classes are used in CSS rules?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. The performance issue is caused by the necessary re-painting of the page. So if there is no re-painting, there is no issue.

Comment: Different CSS methodologies like BEM, for example, is using this pattern, and nobody said about the performance of stacking more than 1 class in a line.

Comment: Thanks @MrLister, I think I get it - so if there are no CSS rules relating to a class, and I change the class on the html tag, the browser won't try to recalculate any styles. I suppose the important point from Umar's video is that this can be expensive when there *are* CSS rules affected by a class on a tag at the top of the DOM.

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas, I think the issue is about adding a class to a tag which has a lot of different levels of other tags inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should only affect performance if you have CSS styles applied to it.

Browser vendors spend a lot of time trying to ensure top notch performance, thus CSS rules are processed so that they can be very efficiently scanned for necessary rendering changes... and even when applying them tries to optimize changes that will cause cascading reflow.

Comment: Thanks @scunliffe, this would seem to be the answer - we only need to worry about those classes if they add CSS rules.